# How to link your own articles on a Pelican blog?

Tags: relative-path, pelican, static-site

I tried to link with the html file name, but it works because they are on the same folder.

```
[Title](./this-is-the-file.html)
```

But it is possible that another article would appear on another folder because of the ARTICLE_URL pattern. Examples:

```
[Title 1](/2014/02/article1.html)
[Title 2](/2014/01/25/article2.html)
```

Is it possible to link your own articles with a reference to the slug ? Any other better solution than the generated HTML file name ?

Comment: I don't think there is a easy way to do this for now. Wish someone would create a plugin for this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As noted in the [documentation](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/stable/content.html#linking-to-internal-content), you can link to other source content files via:

```
[a link relative to content root]({filename}/this-is-the-source-file.md)
```

... or ...

```
[a link relative to current file]({filename}../this-is-the-source-file.md)
```

Pelican will incorporate your chosen URL scheme and automatically determine the proper way to link to the other article.

Comment: This works the same way when writing in reStructuredText instead of Markdown: ```This is `a link <{filename}/somefile.rst`_ to somewhere else.```

Answer (score 3):

The way I do this is by specifying my own sluglines using the `save_as` metadata tag. So if I have a blog post called `my_post.md`, it'll look like this:

```
Title: My Blog Post
save_as: myblogpost.html

This is the world's most boring blog post.
```

That ensures I can link to it at `/myblogpost.html`. Then in some other blog post, I can say:

```
Title: My Second Blog Post
save_as: mysecondblogpost.html

This is the world's second most boring blog post. The most boring blog post is [here]({{ SITEURL }}/myblogpost.html).
```

It's a more flexible and elegant solution that gives you finer-grained control. And if you're not using Pelican for a blog site, it's pretty essential.

Comment: Are you sure you can use SITEURL in the content ? I can use it only in the templates otherwise I get ``WARNING: Replacement Indicator '{ SITEURL ' not recognized, skipping replacement``

Answer (score 0):

To deal with link in rst / restructured text.

Say you want to have link from your second post to first. Here is piece of context from that second post:

```
If you wish to see my first blog post click `here`_

.. _here: first-blog-post
```

And first blog post should have proper slug:

```
First blog post
########################################
:date: 2019-02-18 20:31
:category: entry
:tags: python, blog, first
:slug: first-blog-post
```

I have configuration:

```
ARTICLE_URL = '{date:%Y}/{date:%m}/{slug}.html'
```

and it deals with additional stuff like year, and month. Most probably you can stick with slug instead of having to track HTMLs.