# Relative link in page to file of my site not in «content» folder of Pelican

Tags: relative-path, pelican, static-site

### 1. Briefly

Is it possible to create relative link to file in my site, which is not in `content` folder?

---

### 2. Detail

Condensed structure of my folder tree:

- `content` — folder with my Markdown pages;
- `output` — folder with my converted Markdown → HTML pages;
- `themes` — folder with files of my theme `sashapelican`.

```
D:\Kristinita.bitbucket.io
├───content
│   └───pages
│       └───Sublime Text
│           Example.md
├───output
│   ├───Sublime Text
|       Example.html
├───themes
│   └───sashapelican
│       ├───statica
│       │   ├───images
│       │   │   ├───other_images
│       │   │       clippy.svg
│       └───templates
└───__pycache__
```

Full source of my test site — **https://bitbucket.org/Kristinita/kristinita.bitbucket.org/src**.

I want to create relative link in my `Example.md` file to `clippy.svg` file. Is it possible?

---

### 3. Did not help

1. `{{SITEURL}}/themes/sashapelican/statica/images/other_images/clippy.svg` not worked for me.
2. I read [**documentation**](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/stable/content.html#linking-to-internal-content), but I can find solution only if file `clippy.svg` is situated in `content` folder.
3. Like in [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21970633/5951529) `[Clippy]({filename}/../themes/sashapelican/statica/images/other_images/clippy.svg)` and `[Clippy]({filename}/themes/sashapelican/statica/images/other_images/clippy.svg)` also not worked for me.
4. I don't find solution of my problem in description of [**autostatic**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pelican-autostatic) plugin.

---

### 4. Do not offer

1. Yes, I understand, that I can add my `statica` folder to `STATIC_PATHS` variable → `STATIC_PATHS = ['statica']` in my `pelicanconf.py` file. But all files into `statica` folder will be copied to `output` folder. All files in my `statica` folder is static, I don't want exact duplicates in my site. I will use this method only if we don't have another solutions. Please, do not offer it.

Comment: Not sure I really understand what you want, but `{{SITEURL}}/themes/sashapelican/statica/images/other_images/clippy.svg` can't work as that folder doesn't exist in the generated output. However `{{SITEURL}}/theme/images/other_images/clippy.svg` should exist.

Comment: @MiloslavČíž: I insert `{{SITEURL}}/theme/images/other_images/clippy.svg` into my Example.md file → I run command in terminal `pelican content` → I get ouput `WARNING: Replacement Indicator '{SITEURL' not recognized, skipping replacement`. Thanks.